# Checking out a branch after repo was fetched using git fetch --no-tags

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm in a repo which was fetched like this (I have no control over this checkout)

```
git init
git fetch --no-tags --progress https://myrepo.git +refs/heads/someOtherBranch:refs/remotes/origin/someOtherBranch
```

There's also a `develop` branch in this repo which I'd like to checkout but when I run any combination of the following, I get `error: pathspec 'develop' did not match any file(s) known to git`

```
git fetch
git checkout develop
git checkout origin/develop
```

How can I checkout the develop branch (without going through a `git clone` etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to lack of some configuration variables, `git fetch` without any other options can't work as expected. For a cloned repository, the variable and its value `remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` are automatically set, and the default remote `origin` is automatically added.

In your case, you can specify the remote and the refspec,

```
git fetch https://myrepo.git +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
git checkout develop
```

You can also use

```
git fetch https://myrepo.git develop
git checkout -b develop FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: I edited to specify that the repo was initiated using `git init` so it's not technically cloned using git clone

Comment: @Nightwolf The 2 sets of commands can work in any git repository, a cloned one or an initialized one.